# For looping through a list in django template acting strange

Tags: python, django

**Models**

```
Person
 - name [char]

Team
- players [char]
```

**view.py**

```
 loop through person in Person 
  list.append(Person.name)
 end loop
 Team.player = list
```

I then have a query in a view to grab the list of players in a team... this works fine, and when past to template {{list}} prints correcy ['player1','player2','player3']... when it comes to printing them out individually however..

```
  {% for [players in list %}
    {{players}}
  {% endfor %}
```

this returns the exact same thing as just doing {{list}} with a confusing difference.. ['p l a y e r 1','p l a y e r 2','p l a y e r 3'].... looking at every possible solution to accessing specific values, and none of them work.. I can't do {{list.0}} ect, can anyone notice something wrong that I may be doing?

Comment: Your syntax looks really strange it also doesn't look like python at all. Could you try writing a brand new program from scratch in as few lines as possibly that mimics the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: yeah sure @DustinNunyo

Comment: yes @DustinNunyo is right. Python doesn't have a keyword called loop (at least as far as I know)